# Dynamic data validation based on other cell values, and copying/filling validation criteria relatively down each row (Google Sheets)

Tags: validation, spreadsheet

I am trying to achieve the following situation using Data Validation in Google Sheets.  I've provided a truncated version of situation in the image below.

I would like to set up data validation in Column B that automatically checks the options in column C (or multiple columns in the same row) to populate the dropdown menu for that row.

I did notice that Google Sheets has an option for formulas in the data validation screen and I tried writing an array formula in this area but I have not been having any luck getting any sort of output.

If it can't be done through this menu I would appreciate any idea how to achieve this through scripts.

[image: Spreadsheet illustrating situation]

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to select `list from a range` in the "Criteria" section of the Data Validation editor. Then, select the cells whose values you want to appear in your dropdown.

[image: Example Data Validation settings]

The only issue is that when you try to fill this down across the column, Google Sheets will not update the criteria range. Say you do the following:

1. In cell `B2`, use data validation based on `list from a range` and select `D2:F2` as the criteria range. Now the dropdown in `B2` will have the options *John's Mom, John's Dad, John's Grandma*
2. Then, fill down or copy this cell down across the whole column
3. When you open the dropdown for cell `B3`, it will still have the options *John's Mom, John's Dad, John's Grandma*

Unfortunately Google Sheets does not currently have a built-in solution for copying/filling data validation references or formulas relatively, as far as I know. But it looks like somebody already wrote a nice script in this [Google Docs forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/pBDeCGqzlMI). To avoid just a link as an answer, I'm going to copy in the script and instructions here. Credit to [AD:AM](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!profile/docs/APn2wQfqbPQfY4HkgZ4KQxweHQ4BzRZTtDwCxrAq6cpb1LZnKYxTjmg4XtaonAHTbAzv7gsBNe9k) from Google Docs forum.

How to use their script:

1. Select a range of cells across which you want to copy a data validation rule, *relatively*
2. From the Validation+ custom menu, select the appropriate option (all references relative, columns absolute, or rows absolute)
3. The validation of the upper-left cell will be copied to the rest of the range

[Link to original solution's example Google Sheets with script already included](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nx0z5TwZ7lGa5E1bkzcWNXMJKkPaygcom_vPy84PQME/edit?usp=sharing) - you can save your own copy and then start using.

Or to recreate from scratch, here is the script.

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu
  (
    "Validation+",
    [
      {name: "Copy validation (all relative references)", functionName: "copyValidation"},
      {name: "Copy validation (relative rows, absolute columns)", functionName: "copyValidationColumnsAbsolute"},
      {name: "Copy validation (absolute rows, relative columns)", functionName: "copyValidationRowsAbsolute"}
    ]
  );
}

function copyValidation(rowsAbsolute, columnsAbsolute)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var dv = r.getDataValidations();
  var dvt = dv[0][0].getCriteriaType();
  if (dvt != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) return;
  var dvv = dv[0][0].getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log(dvv);
  for (var i = 0; i < dv.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = i ? 0 : 1; j < dv[0].length; j++)
    {

      dv[i][j] = dv[0][0].copy().withCriteria(dvt, [dvv[0].offset(rowsAbsolute ? 0 : i, columnsAbsolute ? 0 : j), dvv[1]]).build();
    }
  }
  r.setDataValidations(dv);
}

function copyValidationRowsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(true, false);
}

function copyValidationColumnsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(false, true);
}
```

Comment: get the following error when I run this script:
Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.